# Setting property isEnabled of CheckBox control based on action in other control located in usercontrol.

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

Is there easy way to set property IsEnabled to false CheckBox control after clicking Button. Notice that button is in another xaml file. Is it possible to do it without code behind, only in xaml?

MainWindow.xaml

```xaml
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <local:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,54,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

UserControl1.xaml

```xaml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
    >
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: You will need to use code somewhere, either in code-behind or a viewmodel, afaik there's no way to do this in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add a `bool` property, and use a `ToggleButton` instead of a `Button`. Here we bind  the `CheckBox.IsChecked` property to the `bool IsDefault` property (call it what you like) and set the `UserControl.DataContext` property:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" Content="CheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsDefault}" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <local:UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Margin="31,54,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here we bind the `ToggleButton.IsChecked` property to the `bool IsDefault` property:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton Content="Button" IsChecked="{Binding IsDefault}" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now that they are data bound, changing one will update the other.